# PHP - Difference between two times

Tags: php, time

I've created a timing system for a charity race. I'm trying to find the difference between the start time and the finishers time using PHP. I'm not sure I'm recording the times correctly, but this is the start time i just recorded...

```
20180808180653
```

And this is a finisher time...

```
20180808180654
```

The difference between them is roughly 1 hour 24, but when i use...

```
date('h:i:s', $finshTime-$startTime)
```

I get 03:24:20 not 01:34:20.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Would start off converting each those string "dates" into unix times. Maybe look at newer http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: you are printing the date at your timezone, which is UTC+2. Actually you are printing the `h:i:s` part of `1970-01-01T01:34:20Z` (Z means UTC), since timestamp 0 is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date method accepts as "integer Unix timestamp". You are supplying instead a number of seconds (`1` in your example).

```
$start = '20180808180653';
$end = '20180808180654';

$diff = $end - $start;
var_dump($diff);         //1

$d = date('h:i:s', $$diff);
var_dump($d);            //04:00:01

//the above is wrong. You need to try something like the code below   

$dStart = new DateTime($start);
$dEnd = new DateTime($end);
$interval = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
var_dump($interval->format('%h:%i:%s'));
```

I'd be leery using a string representation of a datetime that looks like that. Convert the whole thing into a date format that makes sense like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, or a valid unix time stamp.

Your first approach isn't that far off, you just need to use a [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. I'd guarantee that you can first make an accurate Date or Unix time representation of those strings you are using. Rest should fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the type of  $finshTime and $startTime are integer.
you can use get variable type:

```
 gettype($startTime);
```

if this is the case try this with ():

```
$diff_date = date('h:i:s', ($finshTime - $startTime) );
```

if $startTime and $finshTime are string try this:

```
$diff_date = date('h:i:s', (strtotime($finshTime) - strtotime($startTime)) );
```